# return 0 if no value is found for any value in WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql

I have following query that returns count of unique age of users

```
SELECT name,COUNT(age) FROM visitor_interview WHERE age IN (27,26,23) group by age
```

This query returns following (unique age and their count)

```
array(2) { ["age"]=> int(26) ["count(age)"]=> int(3) } 
array(2) { ["age"]=> int(27) ["count(age)"]=> int(2) }
```

I do not have any user with age 23 therefore, it does not return any value for that

Is there a way I can get count=0 for age 23. Like following

```
array(2) { ["age"]=> int(26) ["count(age)"]=> int(3) } 
array(2) { ["age"]=> int(27) ["count(age)"]=> int(2) }
array(2) { ["age"]=> int(23) ["count(age)"]=> int(0) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by creating a derived table with the ages you are interested in using `UNION` and `LEFT JOIN`ing that to your `visitor_interview` table:

```
SELECT a.age, COUNT(v.age) 
FROM (SELECT 23 AS age UNION SELECT 26 UNION SELECT 27) a
LEFT JOIN visitor_interview v ON v.age = a.age
GROUP BY a.age
ORDER BY a.age
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=572f9eb3ef722cddc1f3c94262fa6e0c)